# How to remove "plugins" from the macOS terminal? (zsh)

Tags: python, macos, keras, terminal, conda

I'm new to installing packages and I just used conda to install **Keras** with **command:-** `conda install -c conda-forge keras`.

Now whenever I open the terminal, some python scripts are being run and my shell now shows `(base) legitmichel777@x86_64-apple-darwin13 ~ %`. I'm using zsh. How do I revert back to my old shell?

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of the terminal screen so that we can understand it better? You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61836238/edit) your post and [add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/519437).

Comment: Looks like Conda is activating the "base" virtualenv when you open up the terminal.